# dvd movie not working

Tags: video, dvd

I have ubuntu 12.10 and I can't play dvd movies. I tried every kmplayer vlc gnomeVLC could not read the file (Input/output error).

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///media/ahsidddiqui/Ubuntu%20OEM%2012.10%20amd64%20UALinux/'. Check the log for details.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///media/ahsidddiqui/Ubuntu%20OEM%2012.10%20amd64%20UALinux/'. Check the log for details.
```

Comment: Have any of the solutions below solved your issue?

Answer (score 11):

This might be caused by not having the correct codecs installed. To be able to play DVDs on Ubuntu, there are a few things you need to do first:

1. Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, either through the software center or the terminal using the following command: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
2. Install libdvdcss using the following command in the terminal:
   `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

You can read more about playing DVDs on the [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

Comment: great answer. I could never play dvd and this solved it. dunno why there aren't more upvotes

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu `16.04` i needed to do some more. I needed to install `libdvdread4` and `libdvdcss` The first one can be installed through `apt`. For the  latter one the installation steps are written in detail in
 `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css`  or [here](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html). After adding these two libs i was able to play original dvd`s on my laptop.

Answer (score -1):

You need Medibuntu for this - here is documentation - what to do :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu